# To implement MongoDb array pagination

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

i am having trouble with pagination in MongoDB array. I have an schema with the following data

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa25dd9a73b615c35505066"),
"Fbid" : "1661115317267347",
"__v" : 0,
"events" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa25dd9500cb334486df5b7"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "9s3ix5n3mwm"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa25dfa500cb334486df5b8"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "32df8pdjh9c"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa25e6e619354309043cb3c"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "1g49hicor87"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa25f4c4351732fb837d9b3"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "q49c8g5l7k"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa25f98c2b85010f4fca6dd"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "pj3467cz5zc"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa29ead0a72530af0a468e6"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "6wduwcs6lvr"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa29ec70a72530af0a468e7"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "g53i9c1ubf5"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa29f840a72530af0a468e8"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "m0sdyzyl9l"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa29f9a0a72530af0a468e9"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "mwo0k55deyo"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa29fa10a72530af0a468ea"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "w4lnpkr1z8f"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa29faa0a72530af0a468eb"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "wxy9uj0trcm"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa29fb20a72530af0a468ec"),
        "event" : "selfie",
        "imageId" : "odpuibgotl9"
    }
],
"email" : "1407258@kiit.ac.in"
```

}

Multiple objects of this type is present in the schema. In the pagination part, i want the page to display a part of array i.e 10 of events array in the schema one time on page. However, next 2 array element should be displayed on next page, along with next object's array. How can I implement it?

I have seen some with `slice` but wasn't able to implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your attempts, it is not quite clear whether you want to paginate documents or events of a single document.

Comment: events of a single document

Comment: event's of a single document is a plain javascript array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array. The answer depends on how you fetch the document and how you navigate to the next page. Add relevant code to the question. The sentence *However, next 2 array element should be displayed on next page, along with next object's array.* is too vague and makes no sense without code.

Comment: It means unlike slice which will leave the last two elements $slice = 8, i want to include last 2 element of array too with the result

Comment: m sorry, if i am not making a bit more sense, i dont know i to put it in a better way.

Comment: sorry mate, but it makes even less sense now. That's a quite common problem and it is why there is a [recommendations  of how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - often code speaks for itself so please, show your attempts. Otherwise the question falls into "unclear what you are asking" category.

Comment: Yes, i understand, i will update it with few more code....

Comment: There is an "events" array in my collection, thats what i am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination you could use the `skip()` and `limit()` operators.

```
// Page 1
db.foo.find().limit(10)

// Page 2
db.foo.find().skip(10).limit(10)

// Page 3
db.foo.find().skip(10).limit(10)
```

Comment: Yes, yes.... i agree, i want to paginate events of a single document, but 10 at a time.

Comment: Yes, and i dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i wasn't able to implement what i want. Had to change the whole DB structure and finally pagination is happening. 
Earlier was storing image id in array, now making an individual document for it.
Here is the structure

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa39904ac370621286099f6"),
"Fbid" : "113161819515501",
"imageId" : "9s76au1zrfs",
"email" : "pigspdsude_1519876920@tfbnw.net",
"event" : "selfie",
"__v" : 0}
```

And the pagination code:

```
 likeImformation.paginate( likeImformation.find({"event":event}),{page:page, limit:5},function(err, data){
    if(data===undefined){
        res.render('event.hbs', {
            name: req.user.displayName

        });
    }
    else{
        console.log("*******************************************");
        console.log(data.docs+"*************"+"alpit");
        console.log("*******************************************");
        res.render('event.hbs', {
            name: req.user.displayName,
            event:data.docs,
            eventName:req.params.event,

        });
    }
})
```

Hope it helps someone.. :-)